# ¿como imprimir todas las llaves de un arreglo en php?

Tags: php, array

```
<? php

  $NombreMenu="";

  $NombreSubMenu="";

  $Menu = array();

  $consulta = 'SELECT cm.nom_menu, csm.nom_sub FROM c_submenu AS csm
               INNER JOIN c_menu AS cm ON csm.Id_sub = cm.Id_menu ORDER BY cm.nom_menu;';

  $resultMenus = $catalogo->obtenerLista($consulta);

  while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultMenus)) {     
     if (array_key_exists($row2['nom_menu'], $Menu)) {
        array_push($Menu[$row2['nom_menu']], $row2['nom_sub']);
     }else{
        $NombreMenu=$row2['nom_menu'];
        $Menu[$NombreMenu]= array($row2['nom_sub']);    
     }                          
  }

  echo '<li> <a>'. key($Menu).' </a> <h1>';
  foreach ($Menu as $menus) {
     foreach ($menus as $key => $value) {
         echo "<br>";
         echo "Submenu:".$value;                            
     }
  } 

?>
```

imprime esto:

> Acervo
>
> Submenu:Catálogo en línea 
> Submenu:Áreas y Ejes 
> Submenu:Subareas
>   Submenu:Tipos Eje/Área 
> Submenu:Cruces por Área 
> Submenu:Cruces por Eje
>   
> Submenu:Cruces Aplicación por Área 
> Submenu:Cruces Aplicación por Eje
>   
> Submenu:Asiganción de aplicaciones 
> Submenu:Metas y Actividades
>   Globales 
> Submenu:Metas y Actividades Generales 
> Submenu:Prioridad
>   
> Submenu:Portadas 
> Submenu:Catálogo de aplicaciones 
> Submenu:Menús por
>   aplicación 
> Submenu:Módulos por menú 
> Submenu:Indicadores
>   
> Submenu:Documentación de procesos 
> Submenu:Bitácora Submenu:Eventos
>   
> Submenu:Noticias

Comment: Las llaves te refieres a la key ?

Comment: si en mi arreglo hay 12  Array ( [0] => Acervo [1] => Administración del sistema [2] => Archivos [3] => Eventos [4] => Exposición [5] => Financieras [6] => Indicadores [7] => Inventario [8] => Logros [9] => Opiniones [10] => Plantilla [11] => Seguridad ) quiero imprimir las 12

Comment: Pero quieres imprimir esto :

- Acervo 
- Administración del sistema
- Archivos 
- Etc

Comment: si que se muestren los 12 para despues ordenarlos en una lista

Comment: Las preguntas que contienen solo código no son bien recibidas, agrega una descripción de lo intentas obtener [edtando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/198174/edit) tu pregunta

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

    $consulta = 'SELECT cm.nom_menu AS nom_menu , csm.nom_sub AS nom_sub FROM c_submenu AS csm
                   INNER JOIN c_menu AS cm ON csm.Id_sub = cm.Id_menu ORDER BY cm.nom_menu';

$result = $conn->query($consulta);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
        echo $row["nom_menu"];
        echo $row["nom_sub"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIE\aplicaciones\MenuAplicaciones.php on line 131

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIE\aplicaciones\MenuAplicaciones.php on line 131

Comment: me marca esos dos errores

Comment: Claro porque tienes que pesarle la conexión de tu base de datos.